# Interpretar cadena de texto como lista

Tags: python, string, lista, archivo

En un punto concreto de mi proyecto tengo una matriz en forma de lista en un archivo de texto. Lo abro como tal, pero el programa lo interpreta como una cadena de texto, imposibilitando su correcto funcionamiento.
para llamar al archivo lo hago de la siguiente manera:

```
texto = open('prueba.txt','r')
matriz = texto.read()
```

Lo que se queda almacenado en la variable matriz es un string y no una lista.

¿Cómo puedo convertirlo?

Gracias.

Comment: Sí, ese código te lee una cadena de texto. La conversión a lista o matriz la tendrás que hacer tú, y depende del formato que use el fichero y la estructura que uses para la lista. Muestra esa información, qué has probado y qué problema *específico* tienes, indica qué lenguaje usas... Lee [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Este código Python 3 lee un archivo (prueba.txt) y divide los caracteres en una lista. `list()` es una función incorporada en Python.

```py
texto = open('prueba.txt', 'r')
matriz = texto.read()
print(list(matriz))
```

Comment: valia con pasar `matriz` por `list()`,de echo `list(matriz)` produce exactamente el resultado deseado
siempre que lo que se espera no es una matriz,sino un vector

Answer (score 0):

Si es una cadena **bien formada** haciendo checkeos previos puedes utilizar lo siguiente para transformarla directamente en matriz o lista:

```
import ast

with open("prueba.txt", 'r') as f:
   lista_o_matriz = ast.literal_eval(f.read())
```

Saludos.